# ACH Payment transfer with Paypal in php

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to search a api of paypal to transfer money from paypal account to bank account means ACH payment.

After searching, i found [this pdf file](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_achpayment_guide.pdf). but i am not able to found api code.

Is it ACH Payment is possible in paypal?
If yes how to do it in php?
what i am looking for is documentation which help me with ach payment. so any help is appreciated.

Sidenote: Sometime ago, I have done ACH payment with Stripe Api. in which i create recipientin stripe account and later transfer money to this recipient. so is the process is same for paypal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a PDF for [payflowpro](/questions/tagged/payflowpro). While it's a PayPal product, it's simply the gateway portion. So you would need a merchant account (i.e. with a bank) that supports ACH, as well as a PayFlow account, to use that service.

It sounds like you're asking about Payments Pro, where PayPal is both your gateway and merchant account. In this case, PayPal does not directly support ACH (it technically happens for PayPal customers but it's not something you control).

To broaden this some, the API doesn't provide you a way to manage your PayPal account via the API. An ACH withdrawal to a bank account can only be triggered by logging in. This falls under the same thing as updating addresses, adding/removing bank accounts, etc.

Comment: what I am trying to do is transfer money from my PayPal account to someone's bank account. Is it possible using PayPal?

Comment: You can't do that through PayPal. ACH is the only thing that can do that can PayPal directly doesn't support that, as outlined in my answer.